# flutter: randomize item count in list View

Tags: flutter

i implemented listView in flutter and it shows product count=5 , but i wanted these 5 items to be generated randomly , is there a way to do it? thanks in advance
ps: i tried code depending on answer below but it gives me error count!=null

```html
Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                          height: 210.0,
                          child: FutureBuilder(
                            future: httpService.getProducts(),
                            builder:
                                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                return Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('Loading...'),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                                return Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('No offers'),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                            
                               var rndItems  = snapshot.data.shuffle();
                                         return ListView.separated(
                                    separatorBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return SizedBox(height: 3);
                                    },
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: rndItems ,
                                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => (PdtItem(
                                        title: snapshot.data[i].title,
                                        imgUrl: snapshot.data[i].imgUrl,
                                        price: snapshot.data[i].price,
                                        pdt2: snapshot.data[i])),
                                  );
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the snapshot.data to be listed in a random order?

Comment: yes exactly , i want itemcount equals random items from snapshot.data

Comment: Try `itemCount: Random.nextInt(snapshot.data.length)`

Comment: it shows an error, Instance member 'nextInt' can't be accessed using static access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the items from snapshot.data to be listed in a random order then you may shuffle the data as follows :

```
....
snapshot.data.shuffle();
....
```

If you want to display random number of items everytime then

```
....
import 'dart:math';
....
var rng = new Random();
var rndItems = rng.nextInt(snapshot.data.length);
....

.....                                    
                    scrollDirectionn: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: rndItems,                                                          
                    itemBuilderr: (ctx, i) => (PdtItem(
.....
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, i tried the second one and it shows me error, The instance member 'rng' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: Did you add the line >>> import 'dart:math'; << at the top of the code?

Comment: I also tried itemCount:snapshot.data.shuffle(), and it didn't work ,error says: itemCount!=null

Comment: If you are adding the import then add the line >>> var rng = new Random();
var rndItems = rng.nextInt(snapshot.data.length);
<<< after snapshot.hasdata.  Then make sure to use >>>  itemCount: rndItems, <<<

Comment: i updated my question cuz these didn't work too, if u please can help

Comment: and i wanted to random the items not no of items, so i used shuffle

Comment: Set ====> itemCount: snapshot.data.length, <====

Comment: how to shuffle data?

Comment: Simply use it as snapshot.data.shuffle();  shuffle with randomise your list.

Comment: Simply use it as ====> else {
                               snapshot.data.shuffle();
                                         return ListView.separated(
                                    separatorBuilder: <====

Comment: thank u i was doing something wrong , thanks again for ur help

Comment: Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.